# Getting class name for logging

Tags: java, logging

To log errors for a given class, I'm accessing the class name like so: 
Is this a 'good' way to return the class name as a String, so it can be used for logging?

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = MyClass.class.getName();
logger.error("Error occurred in "+CLASS_NAME);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up your logging parameters in log4j.xml itself.

For exp -

```
<appender name="swcd-web" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/swcd-web.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

It would log exceptions like this in swcd-web.log file -

```
2012-05-23 16:34:51,632 [main] ERROR com.idc.sage.sso.dynamo.SsoDbStorage - cannot get configuration for max SSO age
```

Comment: The question isn't about log4j.

Answer (score 23):

## Java 8 Solution

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
...

private final static Logger LOG = 
                     LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

Comment: I receive error : The method getLogger(Class<capture#1-of ?>) is undefined for the type LoggerFactory

Comment: to avoid blue-sky's error, be sure to import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; not one with spi in the name.

Answer (score 8):

If you initialize the logger this way:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName())>
```

then the name of the class will be present in every logging event, you don't need to explicitly put it in every log call:

```
logger.error("Error occured while doing this and that");
```

The you can configure the logging service (in *logging.properties* in case of `java.util.logging`, or *log4j.properties* if you use Apache log4j) to include the class name in every log message.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing a lot of people using external library, like log4j, slf4j, jboss.logger and so on...

I prefer the old way, using a simple

```
java.util.logging.Logger
```

It's standard and you don't need libraries to import.

You can initialize it as:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(A.class.getName());
```

and then each time the logger write on a stream know that you used the *A* class:

```
String errorcode = "ABC123";
LOG.log(Level.SEVERE,"This is a very important error with code {0}", new Object[]{errorcode});
```

whatever is you standard stream, for example a console or a logging file, it write something like:

```
[date]     [hour]        [level] [class]       [description]
2020-01-01 00:00:10.123  SEVERE  my.package.A  This is a very important error with code AAA123
```

If you want a log customization, you can use [java.util.logging.Handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html).

At this [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/logging/custom-handler.html) you can find an example of Handler.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
logger.error("Error occured in " + this.getClass().getName());
```

It's easier to mantain if something changes, but there are another ways to do this.

Comment: this.getClass().getName() would give the complete class name (including packages). I would truncate and use only the class name.

Comment: You can use this.getClass().getSimpleName() if you prefer

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not state which logging library you are using I suggest to use **slf4j**. I think it is the easiest you can get. You simply ask for a Logger object from slf4j's `LoggerFactory` like this:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YouerClass.class);
```

now you can use the LOGGER object for logging.

Logging an error for example looks like this:

```
LOGGER.error(yourMessage, throwable);
```

You can send a simple string message or the whole exception.